# On the definition of a random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(O,F,P)$ be a probability space. That is $O$ is a set, $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $O$ and $P$ is a probability measure. Consider a function $f:O\to\mathbb R$.

Would we call $f$ a random variable regardless of whether $f^{-1}(x)\in F$, for any real number $x$, as is required for discrete random variables? What additional conditions should $f$ posses before it is considered a random variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable $f:O\to\mathbb R$ is an $F$-measurable function, meaning for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\{\omega \in O: f(\omega) > \alpha\} \in F.$$

Since $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, other common definitions are equivalent:

$$\{\omega \in O: f(\omega) \geq \alpha\} \in F, \\\{\omega \in O: f(\omega) < \alpha\} \in F,\\\{\omega \in O: f(\omega) \leq \alpha\} \in F, \\etc.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}(x)$ would be a member of the uunderlying set $O$, not a *subset* of $O$.  Thus the question of whether it is a member of $F$ doe not arise.  Maybe you meant the set
$$
f^{-1}(\{x\}) = \{\omega\in O : f(\omega)=x \}.
$$

By the usual definitions, $f$ would not be a random variable on this spacec unless that set is a member of $f$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Yes, I mean the full preimage. Surely, you meant big write $F$ at the end.

Comment: It's quite standard notation to conflate $f^{-1}(x)$ with the pre-image of $x$ under $f$ when $f$ is not explicitly mentioned to be bijective.

Comment: "unless that set is a member of $f$" Sorry? You probably meant *unless that set is a member of* $F$. But then the trouble is that this condition does *not* guarantee that $f$ is measurable.